# Angular2 - convert unfortunately date

Tags: date, angular

I have a problem - I use c# Web.api and Angular2. Thats works but Angular convert the date which I do not want / need. The date of the database is correct and angular add 1 hour

{{item.createdate | date:'H:mm' }}

So it shows 20:30 instead of 19:30 which is stored in the database :(

This is part of json repsone:
"createdate": "2016-11-29T19:30:00",

How can I solve this?

Thank you
Ralf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason is there's no timezone information in the datetime string from the database result.

```
var date = new Date('2016-11-29T19:30:00');
console.log(date); //Tue Nov 29 2016 20:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Written in the Angular2 documentation about the Date Pipe [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html).

The `expression` expects a valid datestring format:

`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 2016-11-29T19:30+01:00)`

```
var date = new Date('2016-11-29T19:30+01:00');
console.log(date);  // Tue Nov 29 2016 19:30:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Comment: Ah... ok, for the moment I resolved this by this
{{item.createdate+"+01:00" | date:'HH:mm'}}

But in summer I would need to add 2 hours. I think I must change the web.api and export the formated timestamp.

Thank you for your quick help!

Comment: @Ralf Yes Timestamp is more safe. And convert it to ``ms`` when working with javascript